# How to get list of files from recycle bin for the volume/disk that was mounted?

Tags: c#, filesystems, com-interop, vhd, recycle-bin

Usually people get list of files inside the Recycle Bin using `Shell32.dll`.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetRecycleBinFilenames()
{
    const int ssfBitbucket = 10;
    Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
    dynamic shell = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    Folder recycleBin = shell.NameSpace(ssfBitbucket);

    foreach (FolderItem2 recfile in recycleBin.Items())
    {
        yield return recfile.Path;
    }

    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(shell);
}
```

I am mounting a VHDX file and want to get a list of files from the Recycle Bin on a mounted external disk/volume.  How can I do this?

Comment: Which recycle bin? There are potentially many.

Comment: You can filter on the Path.

Answer (score 0):

As [@RaymondChen suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37169214/how-to-get-list-of-files-from-recycle-bin-for-the-volume-disk-that-was-mounted/52032991#comment61881996_37169214) you can filter based on the [`Path` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/shell/folderitem-path), which contains the current path of the deleted item...

```
foreach (FolderItem2 recfile in recycleBin.Items())
{
    if (Path.GetPathRoot(recfile.Path) == "X:\\")
        yield return recfile.Path;
}
```

You could also retrieve the path of the directory from which the item was deleted and filter the same way...

```
const int BitBucketItem_OriginalParentPath = 1;

foreach (FolderItem2 recfile in recycleBin.Items())
{
    string originalParentPath = recycleBin.GetDetailsOf(recfile, BitBucketItem_OriginalParentPath);

    if (Path.GetPathRoot(originalParentPath) == "X:\\")
        yield return recfile.Path;
}
```

...however if the item was deleted through a junction/symlink then `originalParentPath` will contain the drive of the junction/symlink, which is not necessarily the drive storing the deleted item.